# Inputting values to a full 2d array

Tags: java

I'm currently trying to figure out how to add values into a full 2d array. Any help would be appreciated.

This is what i currently have.

```
public static ObjectA[][] addValue(ObjectA value, ObjectA[][] oldArray)
{
    //Creates a new array with an extra row
    ObjectA[][] newArray = new ObjectA[oldArray.length +1][oldArray[0].length]

    for (int i= 0 ; i < newArray.length; i++)
    {
        for (int ii = 0; ii <= newArray[0].length; ii++)
        {
            // when the index exceeds the oldArray
            // it will add the value to the newArray
            if (i <= oldArray.length)
            {
                newArray[i][ii] = oldArray[i][ii];//copies all values into newArray
            }
            else
            {
                newArray[i][ii] = value; //adds value to the last row
            }
        }
    } 
    return newArray;
}
```

What I currently have done is input a value to the new row however the method is going to be called multiple times to add more than one value. Which mean it's going to create multiple rows rather than adding to the next available column.

**EDIT:**
mistyped the data type the array and value are suppoed to be objects.

Comment: Are you really need 2d array here? Maybe it is better to use `Vector<Vector<Integer>>` here?

Comment: Or an ArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

First, your code throws an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. Here is why:

Consider the `if (i <= oldArray.length)` clause. Say, `oldArray.length` is `3`. When `i = 3`, `newArray[i][ii] = oldArray[i][ii]` line seeks the `oldArray[3][ii]` elements but there are no such elements. All the possible elements of `oldArray` is `oldArray[0][ii]`, `oldArray[1][ii]` and `oldArray[2][ii]`, since counting starts with `0` in programming.

Second, I didn't get the point of adding another row for each next value. If you're not going to add a set of values to each row, then, why do you consider expanding number of rows?

Comment: Sorry there was a few mistakes in what i wrote. The value and arrays are supposed to be objects. Somewhere else in my code all of the elements in oldArray have objects already assigned to it. What i;m trying to do is if the user wants to add an additional object how do i add to the array since the length of oldArray is already declared which is why i created a newAray with an extra row and copied over the objects in oldArray

Answer (score 0):

This is a typical situation when you need to make a tradeoff between element access complexity and complexity of adding new column

If you need fast column adding without new structure allocation you should use LinkedList as a storage of rows and call list.add(row) every time you need to add a new column so your code will look like:

```
  public static void addValue(int value, LinkedList<int[]> list) {
    int[] row_you_need_to_add = new int[list.get(0).length];
    for (int i = 0; i < list.get(0).length; i++) {
        row_you_need_to_add[i] = value;
    }
    list.add(row_you_need_to_add);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As 2D Array is an Array which consist of an array within an Array. So at every index of 2D array there is another array is present and has a specific size.

```
public static ObjectA[][] addValue(ObjectA value, ObjectA[][] oldArray) {
    ObjectA[][] newArray = new ObjectA[oldArray.length +1][oldArray[0].length]

    for (int i= 0 ; i < newArray.length; i++) {
        for (int ii = 0; ii <= newArray[0].length; ii++) {
            // when the index exceeds the oldArray
            // it will add the value to the newArray
            if (i <= oldArray.length) {
                newArray[i][ii] = oldArray[i][ii];//copies all values into newArray
            } else {
                newArray[i][ii] = value; //adds value to the last row
            }
        }
    } 
    return newArray;
}
```